# save view created programmatically for a fragment and restore in onresume

Tags: android, view, restore, programmatically-created

In my app I have an activity with tabs used to manage 6 fragments . I have some fragments in which I must create some views programmatically based on some data I download from a webservice . How can I save the views I created programmatically and restore them in on resume of the fragments wihtout the need to recreate them every time ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use ***singleton pattern*** for yours fragments.

A ***singleton*** in Java is a class for which only one instance can be created provides a global point of access this instance. The singleton pattern describe how this can be archived.

For example:

```
    public class YourFragment extends Fragment {
      private static YourFragment uniqInstance;

      private YourFragment () {
      }

      public static YourFragment getInstance() {
        if (uniqInstance == null) {
          uniqInstance = new YourFragment();
        }
        return uniqInstance;
      }
      .........
}
```

When you want to access your fragment should call:

```
YourFragment.getInstance();
```

If you want to access method in your fragment should call:

```
YourFragment.getInstance().yourMethod();
```

Of course the method which you access must be declare public.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer , it is useful in some cases but it is not the optimal solution in my case . I was already calling the creation of the fragment only once . While I was waiting for answers I had found some sort of solution by my own . I had made the root view of the fragment a variable of the fragment itself and every time the OnCreateView is called i only inflate the view if the view is null , otherwise it returns the same view I had created previously . Now the problem is to update the views when i detect data update from the webservice